# On PhpStorm, how to display JS/CSS erros on PHP files

Tags: javascript, php, css, syntax-error, phpstorm

We are evaluating PhpStorm.

It seems JS and HTML errors are not displayed in  PHP files.

For instance in a file "test.php" having:

```
<style>
    div {
        color: bl;
        uhiuh

    }
</style>
```

Will only report "bl" is a mismatched property. But no errors on "uhiuh". The same code in test.html report well the error.

Same with javascript in test.php :

```
<script>
    fzefz(
</script>
```

Will report only warning for fzefz being undefined. The same code in test.html will report an error "expression expected".

It seems linked to this issue, but their is no move on it:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18963

So my question is, is it possible to highlight JS/CSS errors on PHP files ? (i tried using using template data language by giving HTML language to the folder containing my php view files which contains mixed php/html/css/js, -https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/syntax-highlighting-php-in-js.html- , but it don't display js/css errors).

I should mentions that in the php files their is PHP too, so i cannot just set those files in HTML because it will loose php errors, completions, etc.

From practical point those php files are symfony view files, so mixing php/html/js/css. This is so common that i don't understand why it is not natively correctly handled. Actually i use NetBeans and mixed php/html/js/ccs is very well handled with same reporting than full html files.

I hope their is some way to solution this, because php/symfony is very well handled by PhpStorm.

Thanks.

Comment: PHPStorm is commercial software and as such your questions about the product are probably more suited for their support group than here - https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/?phpstorm

Comment: @CaitLANJenner possibly, but then there is a `phpstorm` tag on SO, with close to 6000 questions.  My experience with IntelliJ products is that there is more knowledge and responsiveness here than on their so-called support.

Comment: I am trying to avoid mixing php/html/js/css.
It makes my Life much easier :-)